# Python check if two numbers are between two numbers

Tags: python, numbers

I try to check if two numbers are between two numbers.

This is what I tried but it does not work:

```
for i in saptamani:
    number1 = str(23.04)
    number2 = str(27.04)
    if i[0] <= number1 <= i[1] and i[0] <= number2 <= i[1]:
        print("4")
    else:
        print("nu este")
```

`i.0` and `i.1` are formatted like `number1` and `number2`.

Example:

```
i.0 = 22.04
i.1 = 29.04
```

Comment: What is ```saptamani``` in your code?

Comment: 'does not work ok' is not a clear enough description of what doesn't work. Please provide a [mcve] with input data and the output vs your expected output.

Comment: Why converting input number into strings?

Comment: I updated my question. @RobertoCaboni I converting input number into strings because of this:TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about what you have, but you cannot compare two strings. So if you have a list, you can convert them into float, and then compare:

```
num = [['22.04','29.04'],['30','31']]
for i in num:
    i = [float(j) for j in i]
    if i[0] <= number1 <= i[1] and i[0] <= number2 <= i[1]:
        print("4")
    else:
        print("nu este")
```